# python manage.py syncdb not working correctly

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I played around with Django, python and MySQL; and have installed and made them work when do import django, import MySQLdb through python command line.

But when I try to execute python manage.py syncdb in the root directory of the project, I got the following error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 415, in get_server_version
    self.cursor().close()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 387, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (13)")
```

What would be the possible problem? Seems like connection error stuff? I am newbie here, thanks for any help :)

I attached my settings.py file:

```
  # Django settings for mysite project.
   DEBUG = True
   TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': '',                      
        'USER': 'localhost',                 
        'PASSWORD': '',                 
        'HOST': '',                     
        'PORT': '',                     
    }
}

  TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

  LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

  SITE_ID = 1

  USE_I18N = True

  USE_L10N = True

  USE_TZ = True

  MEDIA_ROOT = ''

  MEDIA_URL = ''

  STATIC_ROOT = ''

  STATIC_URL = '/static/'

  STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  )

  STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
  )


SECRET_KEY = 'wke73b4pm&amp;s-g(ra*to+ykxe*3@0h=nrnt(v&amp;3kf)fx=co*72@'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

I could successfully log into the mysql database using the command line:
mysql -u localhost

After making the HOST = "127.0.0.1", I got an updated error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 60, in handle_noargs
    tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 896, in table_names
    return self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py", line 33, in get_table_list
    cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 114, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1046, 'No database selected')
```

Comment: it can't connect to your database. please check the last line

Comment: you are trying to connect to a mysql db that you are referencing as "localhost" when this is not the mysql server for you

Comment: Update the question and add your `settings.py` file

Comment: do this - in the shell, do `mysql -u <username> -p -h<host> <appname>`. See if you can get in. If not, you have problem in the credentials to access the database server or the database instance

Comment: Hi Karthikr, I could get in using mysql -u localhost

Comment: Hi Burhan, I already uploaded. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add database name and port number ..

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'Database_name',                 
        'USER': 'root',                    
        'PASSWORD': 'root',                
        'HOST': '',                     
        'PORT': '3306',                  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `HOST` in the database settings. Either use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Apparently when host is not specified, mysqldb defaults to unix domain sockets instead of using regular hostname/port.

Comment: Hi Plaes, the empty '' for HOST indicates it is a localhost. I added that even for the try purpose, but still not working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @leoooo When the error message says that: ```Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (13)")```, there must be something wrong with the `HOST` value.

Comment: I replace the empty string of HOST to "127.0.0.1" and got the above error I edited in my original post...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a schema (let's name it my_db_schema) in MySQL first and then specify it's name under NAME.

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'my_db_schema',                      
        'USER': 'localhost',                 
        'PASSWORD': '',                 
        'HOST': '',                     
        'PORT': '',                     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly same problem. DATABASES in settings.py need to set value for both HOSTNAME and PORT.

In my case, mysql uses host "localhost:3306". When I set PORT(in settings.py) value to 3306 it works.